# Find the value of a^b?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

Given a series as

f(n)=1^1 * 2^2 * 3^3 * ......n^n
since n can be very large

Find the value of f(n)/f(r)*f(n-r)

and output it modulo m where m is any prime.

Now 
My approach is

f(n)=1^1%m * 2^2%m  * 3^3%m ...... n^n%m

then find the value

(f(n)%m/f(r)%m * f(n-r)%m)%m

Is this modular arithematic will work for non-prime numbers also

Comment: Well u can see that its quite clear

Comment: nopes @Integrator

Comment: Did I asked u a code ....Its just a simple math problem

Comment: I would appreciate any approach by which i can the value of  f(n)/f(r)*f(n-r)

Comment: This question comes from the current CodeChef _November Challenge 2014_ ([Fombinatorial](http://www.codechef.com/NOV14/problems/POWERMUL)). This contest ends on 17 Nov 2014, and this question will remain locked until after then.